Azure CDN Unexpected Caching Behaviour
Azure SWA sitting behind a Front Door CDN Profile. Caching is enabled in Profile, caching headers are configured in staticwebapp.config.json and are correctly coming through in responses.
I want certain files to be allowed to cached either in browser or CDN but always be revalidated to guarantee the the latest files are served.
If I'm not mistaken I should be able to achieve this behaviour with either Cache-Control: "no-cache" or "must-revalidate, max-age=0".
With either of those values I would expect that if the browser had the file cached, it would attempt to revalidate with the origin, receive a 304 status response and use the cached file - and similarly, if not cached in browser but cached in CDN, the CDN would revalidate with origin and then serve the file from the CDN not the origin.
Instead what I'm seeing is that regardless of the file being cached in the browser or in theory being cached in the CDN, the file is fetched from the origin every request and it's a 200 status response with header "x-cache: TCP_MISS"
If I simply change the config for the header to "must-revalidate, max-age=1" - I then start seeing the expected behaviour:

if cached in browser, for 1 sec the cached response is used
if cached in browser after 1 sec it's a 304 status response with x-cache: TCP_REVALIDATED_HIT - so revalidating correctly as expected
if not already cached in browser but in theory should be cached in CDN it's a 200 status response with x-cache: TCP_REVALIDATED_HIT - indicating it's been served from the CDN cache after first being revalidated (I think?)

In all cases (no-cache or max-age=0 or max-age=1) the requests from the browser contain the same headers including: 'if-modified-since' & 'if-none-match'.
Is Azure treating "no-cache" or "must-revalidate, max-age=0" incorrectly or is there some other reason why revalidation does not seem to work with these settings?
